# how disable appearance safari radion button

Tags: javascript, css, ios, safari

I want to remove the standard buttons from the radio buttons, I did it and it looks fine. But not on safari.

i try this, but nothing changes. I test on ios 11.4

```css
input {
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
  position: absolute;
  appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
```